# What are all of the Runescape chat badges and what do they mean?

Tags: runescape

In RuneScape, some players and moderators get a special icon in front of their name. What are all of them, and what do they mean?

I'm asking because I saw one I do not recognize, and I want to learn more.

[image]

This is the one I am specifically asking about, though I want to learn about all of them.

Comment: I know silver crown/silver star means its a player moderator, but other than that I'm not sure

Comment: See this link for the moderator icons, but I'm not sure if its an exhaustive list or not http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Moderator

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein  that has all of the moderater ones, but there must be more of these "prefixes," like the one I snipped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one in question you point out denotes a player that is an Ironman. Check out this link on the [wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Chat#Badges). There are 7 badges currently in the game including this one.

- There are 3 crown's, gold, silver, and purple which represent Jagex Mods, Player Mods, and Community Partners (AKA Local Mods) respectively .
- The blue star shows a player who has purchased premium membership ([see here](https://runescape.wiki/w/Membership_Package#2013)). Note that player mods who have purchased this package will show a silver star.
- A red skull which shows a Hardcore Ironman.

Also there is a hidden eighth badge for Forum Mods that is a green crown. This one does not show in game though and only shows on the forums.